# Stripe Javascript, function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I having trouble to make my my Javascript, I look over similar answer on SoF without any help..
I am configuring stripe payment gateway and what I would like is base on a select button updating the order volume, I would like to edit the price on the button so for the fixed price of 10 if the user select the price is 10 is he selects 2 the price will update to 20.

The thing is I ALWAYS get that my function setprice is not defined .. do not know why or what to do .. please helpp ;)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}


<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<div class="container stripe-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 stripe-info-container">
      {% if messages %}
              <div class="messages" role="alert">
                  {% for message in messages %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ message }}</li>
                  {% endfor %}
              </div>
      {% endif %}
      <form action="{% url "website:checkout_page" %}" method="POST" id="payment-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        NUMBER OF CREDIT
        <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="pick-number-assessements" onchange="setprice()">
          <option value=1 >1 credits - 1 Team</option>
          <option value=2 >2 credits - 2 Teams</option>
          <option value=3 >3 credits - 3 Teams</option>
          <option value=4 >4 credits - 4 Teams</option>
          <option value=5 >5 credits - 5 Teams</option>
        </select>
      </div>
        BILLING INFORMATION
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
              <input name="name_on_card" id="name_on_card" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name on card - Jenny Rosen" required>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">

                <select name="country" class="form-control" id="country">
                  <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                  <option value="AT">Austria</option>
                  <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                  <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
                  <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                  <option value="CN">China</option>
                  <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
                  <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                  <option value="FR">France</option>
                  <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                  <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
                  <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
                  <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                  <option value="JP">Japan</option>
                  <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
                  <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
                  <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
                  <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                  <option value="NO">Norway</option>
                  <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
                  <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
                  <option value="ES">Spain</option>
                  <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
                  <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
                  <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                  <option value="US" selected="selected">United States</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip code" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company">
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>


        PAYMENT INFORMATION
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div id="card-element"></div>
              <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Pay Now - <span id="cost"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
function setprice() {
  var x = document.ready.getElementById("pick-number-assessements").value;
  document.ready.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>


<script>

(function(){
  // Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('#');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
base: {
  color: '#32325d',
  lineHeight: '18px',
  fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
  fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
  fontSize: '16px',
  '::placeholder': {
    color: '#aab7c4'
  }
},
invalid: {
  color: '#fa755a',
  iconColor: '#fa755a'
}
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {
           style: style,
           hidePostalCode: true,
});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
if (event.error) {
  displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
} else {
  displayError.textContent = '';
}
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();


var credit= {
    credit : document.getElementById('pick-number-assessements').value,
}

var creditNumb = Number(credit["credit"])

var price = 60



var options= {
    name : document.getElementById('name_on_card').value,
}

stripe.createToken(card,options).then(function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Inform the user if there was an error.
    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
  } else {
    // Send the token to your server.
    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
  }
});
});
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  alert(token.id)
  //form.submit();
}
}


)();

</script>

{% endblock%}
```

Comment: Try moving the script block that has the definition for set price above any logic that has that method as an inline binding.

Comment: Can you please show the exact error message. It looks like `document.ready` would be `undefined` instead of `setprice`. Notice also, that `getElementById` is a method of `document` only, elements don't have it.